# How to keep open the current tab after reload the page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to keep the last tab clicked open after reloading the page because for the moment, after reloading the first tab is always open. Can you help me pls?

**JavaScript :**

```js
const onglets = document.querySelectorAll('.onglets');
const contenu = document.querySelectorAll('.contenu');
let index = 0;
onglets.forEach(onglet => {
  onglet.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (onglet.classList.contains('active')) {
      return;
    } else {
      onglet.classList.add('active');
    }
    index = onglet.getAttribute('data-anim');
    for (i = 0; i < onglets.length; i++) {
      if (onglets[i].getAttribute('data-anim') != index) {
        onglets[i].classList.remove('active');
      } else {
        onglets[i].classList.add('activeContenu');
      }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < onglets.length; i++) {
      if (onglets[i].classList.contains('active')) {
        console.log(i);
      }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < contenu.length; j++) {
      if (contenu[j].getAttribute('data-anim') == index) {
        contenu[j].classList.add('activeContenu');
        contenu[j].removeAttribute('hidden');
      } else {
        contenu[j].classList.remove('activeContenu');
        contenu[j].setAttribute('hidden', "")
      }
    }
  })
})
```

**HTML Code :**
The content part is mostly Django forms

```html
<div class="container-onglets">
  <div class="onglets active" data-anim="1">Statut</div>
  <div class="onglets" data-anim="2">Fonction</div>
  <div class="onglets " data-anim="3">Contact</div>
</div>

<div class="contenu activeContenu" data-anim="1">
  content
</div>

<div class="contenu" data-anim="2" hidden>
  content
</div>

<div class="contenu " data-anim="3" hidden>
  content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localstorage

`localStorage.setItem('active' , 'true')`

Comment: where should i add this codeline ? On Html code ? At the end or at the beginning ?